# Submitted Forms not Encoding +'s when using method="get"

Tags: html, forms, http, http-get

With the following form

```
<form target="dialogiframe" action="ConfigUpdate.cvx" id="TestForm" 
    name="TestForm" method="get">
    <input name="test" type="text" size="40" value="A Sum 1+2=3"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Set" />
</form>
```

the parameters of the submitted request are encoded as follows

```
test=A+Sum+1+2=3
```

After that is decoded, it gives the incorrect value of "A Sum 1 2=3" as the + in the parameter is not encoded (neither is the = ), and this is converted into a space.

if I change the method to post, then parameters are encoded correctly as

```
test=A+Sum+1%2B2%3D3
```

and is then converted correctly.

I know I should use POST and indeed am going through my pages and am converting them, but am I missing anything in the form definition to make the GET encode correctly?

Tested with IE8 and FF10, pages in <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a known issue with using GET as the form method. Generally you should use the POST method with your forms.

From: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

> The official recommendations say that "GET" should be used if and only if the form processing is idempotent, which typically means a pure query form. Generally it is advisable to do so. There are, however, problems related to long URLs and non-ASCII character repertoires which can make it necessary to use "POST" even for idempotent processing.

Comment: Thanks for the info, interesting read, I've already swapped my forms thats were GET to POST, some were already POST since then were sending in JSON objects. Just another of those issues I'll have to try and keep in mind, newish to web deveolpment and seem to spend most of my time battling inconsistnecies instead of codeing the apps (already using mootools to help on that).